# Running a jQuery script in a Wordpress template

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, templates, attr

I'm trying to run the following script inside of the header.php file of a Wordpress site:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        jQuery('[href=#membership]').attr( 'data-menu-top', '500' );
    });
</script>
```

When I run:

```
jQuery('[href=#membership]').attr( 'data-menu-top', '500' );
```

...in Firebug's console it works properly but placed in the script block inside the header.php file it is not adding the attribute to the anchor like it should. I've run out of ideas.

*I've tried moving the script block around to many places including the footer.php just before the closing body tag, but nothing seems to be working.

--**UPDATE**--
I got it. I think it was a combination of another plugin's JQuery syntax error that I fixed and improper targeting.

Here is my final, working code:

```
<script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            jQuery('#menu-item-14 a').attr( 'data-menu-top', '25' );
            jQuery('#menu-item-11 a').attr( 'data-menu-top', '1300' );
            jQuery('#menu-item-12 a').attr( 'data-menu-top', '500' );
            jQuery('#menu-item-28 a').attr( 'data-menu-top', '500' );
            jQuery('#menu-item-13 a').attr( 'data-menu-top', '500' );
        });
    </script>
```

I'm still tinkering with getting the right attribute from a styling perspective but it's showing up in the source properly.

By the way, this was in pursuit of a proper hash navigation using the [Skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.com/skrollr/) library in Wordpress.

Comment: Are you enqueuing the jquery source to your page or just slapping that `<script>` tag up there?

Answer (score 0):

always have `wp_head();` just before the closing `</head>`, a requirement by Wordpress.

also for the footer, have `wp_footer()` just before the closing `</body>`

This is in the case you are using the jquery script  inside `<script>` tag. Better enqueue it using: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 0):

Just try using:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('[href=#membership]').attr( 'data-menu-top', '500' );
});
```

Comment: I got it. I think the problem was a combination of another error and improper targeting. See above